# how to fetch data from firebase flutter?

Tags: database, flutter, backend, flutter-getx

Here is my model and I wanna store this data in a list ,using getx .null safety method is on.

```
    var productlist = <Productmodel>[].obs;


  Productmodel.frommap( DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
        id = snapshot['id'];
        productname = snapshot['name'];
        price = snapshot['price'];
        image = snapshot['image'];
        brand = snapshot['brand'];
      }
```

[data in firebase database is shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwR6f.png)

Answer (score 0):

In this way, you can access the data by giving the names collection and field.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFGLe.png)

Comment: i wanna store the data in a list in a controller file ,in view file i will just call the list and using listviewbuilder i will display the list.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

try this method...

```
Future<void> getAllData() async {
   List<Productmodel> productModelList = [];

   var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("product").doc('CWvaDGh5ZaCznGtLnq6A').get();
   List dataList = data.data()?['product'];
   
   for (var element in dataList) {
     productModelList.add(Productmodel.fromJson(element));
   }

  print('productModelList : ${productModelList.toList()}');
}
```